# PhoneGap / Cordova "click" working in browser, but not working on Developer App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, phonegap

I have managed to create a login/signup screen, which works perfectly when served by PhoneGap and viewed in a browser.

However when tested on an iPhone using the PhoneGap App, the "click" function no longer works.

```
var myApp = new Framework7();
var $$ = Dom7;

// Handle Cordova Device Ready Event
$$(document).on('deviceready', function() {

    //wait for signup page to be fully loaded
    myApp.onPageInit('signup', function (page) {

        //event listener for signup button
        var signupButton = document.getElementById("signup");

        if(signupButton) {
            signupButton.addEventListener("click", signup, false);
        }

        //on click of signup button
        function signup() {

           login code here
        }
    });
});
```

I am using this "addEventListener" method instead of:

```
$("#signup").on("touchend", function (){signup()});
$("#signup").on("click", function (){signup()});
```

After they also did not work on mobile, and stumbling across this question in an attempt to find a solution:

[cordova/phonegap onclick doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829871/cordova-phonegap-onclick-doesnt-work)

Do these methods / handlers behave differently in a browser vs on the PhoneGap app?

Comment: `$$(document)` ? Was that just a typo? and `on.('click')` should work (depending on version also)

Comment: sorry, there should be a couple of lines about that, I'll edit it now

Comment: Are you even using jQuery? If not `on()` wouldn't work anyways

Comment: Yes, using 3.2.1.

Comment: jQuery mobile however doesn't seem to agree, I get this:

jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:3337 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue on iOS and had to add e.preventDefault() to resolve the issue.

```
$('#signup').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    signup();
});
```

Comment: Just tried this, same result, button does nothing, and no "login failed" popup as there is in a browser!

Comment: This worked, the problem now is iOS ATS not allowing the Ajax post to a local host (no SSL), but that is a different problem!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting you element `#signup` to have a css rule of `cursor:pointer`, then try `$('#signup').on('click', function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

Ok for me the issue was having the button events defined as a result of "window.onload" or "document.addEventListener('deviceready'", I tried both, when I placed the handler definition in my html file it worked, so looks like a bug.

So this now works,

```
$("#clr").on("click", function () {
   $("#mylabel").html("");
});
```

I used the hello app when I created my project and it uses the "app" class.